# Simple notation question: pdf for mle of uniform?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, density-function, uniform-distribution, notation

I have simple notation question related to pdf for  mle of uniform $U(0,\theta)$.

Given following pdf  $f(\hat{\theta}_{MLE}) = \frac{n \cdot \hat{\theta}_{MLE}^{(n-1)}}{\theta^n} $ , I'm confused whether it is ok to have estimator and estimate in same formula? If not, what is the correct form and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no problem having the estimator and the parameter (estimate) in the same formula. The estimator $\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE}}$ is the stochastic variable, the *argument* of the density function, while the parameter is an unknown constant, yes, the parameter of the distribution. So, what you have is correct.